# Exponential as power series

Tags: convergence-divergence, power-series, taylor-expansion, exponential-function

Is there a function that does not depend on $a$ such that $\sum_{x=1}^\infty \frac{a^x}{x!}f(x) = \mathrm e^{-a}$?

Just to be clear, the summation starting from 1 is intentional, otherwise the solution would be trivial.

Comment: So, what happens when you take $k$ derivatives (with respect to $a$) and evaluate at $a=0$?

Comment: Or how about just evaluate at $a = 0$?

Comment: Sorry for the vagueness, please assume $a \in \mathbb{R^+}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is impossible because $e^{-a}$ already has a power series centered at $a=0$ with a nonzero constant term and [power series are unique](http://unapologetic.wordpress.com/2008/09/18/uniqueness-of-power-series-expansions/).